# Tiempo de ejecución en un autoejecutable

Tags: r, cmd

Hago un script en R, por ejemplo, crear un df

```
df = data.frame(dim=sample(letters, replace=T, 2e6), fact1=rnorm(2e6),
                   fact2=rnorm(2e6, 20, 50))

write.table(df, file = "Ejemplo1.txt", row.names = FALSE)
```

y un .bat que lo ejecute.

Cuando ejecuto el .bat sale la pantalla negra del cmd de windows.

¿Hay alguna forma de indicar en esa pantalla el tiempo que queda para que se termine de ejecutar el script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según tu código la respuesta rápida es NO, no puedes, la función `write.table()` no implementa ninguna función "call-back" por ejemplo, para informar las filas escritas.

Una alternativa es crear un "wrapper" a `write.table()` que gracias a que puede hacer un "append" y por esto, podemos dividir la grabación del archivo en múltiples partes y en este caso informar un estatus.

```
write.table.status <- function(df, name, status_by_n=1, status_fun=function(n) {}, ...) {
  n <- ceiling(nrow(df) / status_by_n)
  rows_to_save <- split(1:nrow(df),rep(1:n,each=status_by_n))
  for (rows in rows_to_save) {
    tmp <- df[rows,]
    append_rows <- ifelse(head(rows, 1) == 1, FALSE, TRUE)
    col_names <- !append_rows
    write.table(x=tmp, file=name, row.names = FALSE, append=append_rows, col.names=col_names)
    status_fun(tail(rows, 1))
  }
}
```

Ahora simplemente creamos la función que va a informar la cantidad de filas grabadas:

```
mensaje <- function(n) {
  print(paste("filas escritas:", n))
}
```

E invocamos la ejecución de esta nueva función, por ejemplo para a informar cada 500.000 filas:

```
write.table.status(df, "Ejemplo1.txt", 500000, mensaje)

[1] "filas escritas: 500000"
[1] "filas escritas: 1000000"
[1] "filas escritas: 1500000"
[1] "filas escritas: 2000000"
```

Comment: Gracias. El código q puse fue lo primero que se me ocurrió, podría ser un script completo. Con una respuesta anterior (que creo ha sido borrada) me dio la pista para investigar y di con lo que buscaba (winProgressBar y del estilo). Pero esta forma de  partir el df en trozos e ir avisando es muy curiosa.

Comment: Hola @DudaR, yo entendí que tu pregunta apuntaba en como mostrar un progreso a la hora de salvar una gran cantidad de información con `write.table()`, dónde ciertamente no puedes si salvas de una, todas las filas. ahora si tu ejemplo no es representivo del script que tienes tal vez mi respuesta no sea adecuada. Mostrar un progreso es fácil, agregando `print()` a tu Script con los mensajes adecuados. Las barras de progreso también son efectivas, pero son más bien útiles cuando tienes algún ciclo explicito dónde sabes cuantas vueltas se va a dar.

Comment: Hola Patricio, tu respuesta es perfecta y me ha servido de mucho.